# jQuery selector help

Tags: jquery

Good Morning,

I am trying to write a selector that would select all rows that contain a span element that has a class of "cancelMenu".

Is either of these better than the other? Or is there an even better way to write it?

```
 $("span.cancelMenu").closest("tr");
 $("tr > span.cancelMenu");
```

Any thoughts or ideas? I am using the first one and it works but it seems like I am only targeting one row. I really want all rows at once.

Thanks,
~ck

Comment: The second selector is selecting the span, not the tr.

Answer (score 5):

You can the [`:has`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/has) pseudo-selector:

```
$("tr:has(span.cancelMenu)");
```

Comment: this will select the span, non the row

Comment: won't that select the `span` and not the `tr` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("tr:has(span.cancelMenu)");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to select the row (tr) and not the span you can use parent():

```
$('span.cancelMenu').parent('tr');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with something like

```
$("span.cancelMenu").each(function(i) {
   //$(this).parent() is the row
});
```